# tikz two coloured arrows between two rows of matrix

Tags: amsmath, tikz-arrows

```
\begin{equation}
B = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b\\
    \cdots\\
    c\\
    d\\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

This is my code on Latex, where i create a displayed Matrix B, which is of generic size. Because a,b and c,d are equal in their visual form, i want to show with a small text on top of an arrow, that they are indeed different.

I thought about drawing horizontal arrows from left to the right in front of ab and cd, but in the line inbetween both entries, but tikz is a very unknown chapter for me.

Is there anyone interested in finding a solution for my problem?[image].

The arrow's dont need to come from the left side, also the right side is a possible solution. They just have to be simple as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    fit,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
}   % quelques librairies pour tikz

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node (B) {$B=$};
    \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=), matrix anchor=west, right=1em of B]
    {
        a \\
        b \\
        \cdots\\
        c\\
        d\\
    };
    \node [fit=(M-1-1) (M-2-1), draw, ellipse, inner sep=-3pt, red, pin={[pin distance=1.5em, pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt}] above right:$X$}] {};
    \node [fit=(M-4-1) (M-5-1), draw, ellipse, inner sep=-3pt, blue, pin={[pin distance=1.5em, pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt}] below right:$Y$}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{equation}
\label{VN_allg}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node (V) {$V_n=$};
\matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
matrix anchor=west, right=0.5em of V]
{
    v_{12}^T \\
    v_{11}^T - v_{22}^T\\
    \cdots \\
    v_{12}^T \\
    v_{11}^T - v_{22}^T\\
};
\node [fit=(M-1-1) (M-2-1), draw, rectangle, inner sep=0pt, red, pin={[pin
distance=1.5em, pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt}] above right:{Ansicht 1}}] {};
\node [fit=(M-4-1) (M-5-1), draw, rectangle, inner sep=0pt, blue, pin={[pin
distance=1.5em, pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt}] below right:{Ansicht n}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

Thanks. It is ( haven't managed to link my overflow account with exchange..). I customized it to a more simple appearance, and -by the way, get into it a little.

Because I need to reference this equation, I combined it with a simple equation-environment, and changed the delimiters to the right ones for matrices (was vector).

[image]